# What URL do I recommend to users of my managed package app?

Tags: managed-package

In September, I created a developer account on Salesforce. I began working on an app for my company. At first, the URL that I used looked like this:

https://c.na35.visual.force.com/apex/HeddySearch

But I just realized it now looks like this:

https://privateincinfo.na35.visual.force.com/apex/HeddySearch

I assume that is because I created a namespace prefix?

I've packaged my app as a managed package. Then I created a completely new developer account, unrelated to the first one. I copy and pasted the "Install URL" from the first account and I emailed it to the second account, then I clicked on it and logged in as the second account.

This URL seems to work for the new account:

https://privateincinfo.na35.visual.force.com/apex/HeddySearch

But is that the URL that I am suppose to tell to anyone who uses my managed package?

We hope to release this in the Salesforce App Exchange.

I am curious what URL I should tell to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how they'll be linking to your page.

If they can use a Visualforce Page type button for this page, they can just select the page, and the platform will take care of it.

If they can use URLFOR, such as in a formula field or in a Visualforce page, they can use `{!$Page.privateincinfo.HeddySearch}`.

In most normal cases, you can tell them to simply use `/apex/privateincinfo__HeddySearch`, which is an absolute URL on their domain; salesforce will magically redirect them to the appropriate URL for their installation, which may be something like https://privateincinfo.na8.salesforce.com, https://privateincinfo.customdomain.my.salesforce.com/, etc.

You should never reference the domain name directly in a URL, as it may cause them to go to the wrong org/location, especially if they have multiple logins in multiple orgs. Recommend using the methods above instead.